# How to declare a variable in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, var

I am new to scala. I come from a c++ a background. In c++ i was able declare a variable then initialize it later.

```
int x;
x=0;
```

How do I do it scala. I have a Map variable. I want to declare without any value. Then later I want to put a value in it. I want to do something like

```
var mp: Map[Int, ParticipationStateTransition] = Nil
```

or

```
var mp: Map[Int, ParticipationStateTransition] = new Map[Int, ParticipationStateTransition]
```

But the interpreter is saying that I cannot do it. It says

> Nil doesn't conform to Map

How do I do it?

Comment: _"I want to declare without any value."_ Why would you want to do that if there's nothing there yet? If you want to express a thing that's maybe a Map, but maybe nothing, why not use [an option type](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option)?

Comment: Use `null` instead of `Nil`

Comment: In scala, only `class members` can be `declared` without `initializing`. You will have to `initialization` then to some value. In such requirements use of `Option` is recommended. `val io: Option[ Int ] = None`

Comment: @Carsten Its a class variable. Later methods of the class will insert value inside it

Comment: @SergeyLagutin, if I write null then can later methods use it or do they have to initialize it again to use?

Comment: @SergeyLagutin `null` wont work. try `var Map[ Int, Int ] = null` and you will get `error: pattern must be a value: Map[Int,Int]; Note: if you intended to match against the class, try `case _: Map[_,_]`.

Comment: Is there nothing called Garbage Value in scala?

Comment: Scala and other functional languages discourage the idea of null-values.  You can use `var mp: Map[Int, ParticipationStateTransition] = Map.empty[Int, ParticipationStateTransition]`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, that's exactly what I was looking for. Do other languages have it?

Comment: Languages which intend to be functional like Haskell, F# or which are inspired by some functional concepts like Rust have similar features.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72826/discussion-between-eddard-stark-and-sarvesh-kumar-singh).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

//declaration

```
var mp: Map[Int, ParticipationStateTransition] = Map.empty[Int, ParticipationStateTransition]
```

//assigning value to mp

```
mp+=(1 -> "value1",  2-> "value2")
```

Comment: You could use type inference here: `var mp: Map[Int, ParticipationStateTransition] = Map.empty`